# Converting an LineString to h3 hexagons using srai

Tags: geometry, geopandas, h3

I try to convert an shapely LineString to a sequence of h3 hexagons.
For that task [srai](https://kraina-ai.github.io/srai/0.3.1/api/h3/#h3_to_shapely_geometry) offers the funciton `h3_to_geoseries` unfortunately the function runs into the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'
```

Could you give some advice how I can avoid this problem?